# Gspread Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
cell_matrix = []
init_colnum=colnum
init_rownum=rownum

worksheet = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name)

if resize:
    worksheet.add_rows(df.shape[0]+init_colnum)
    worksheet.add_cols(df.shape[1]+init_rownum)

t_all=0
t1 = time.time()
i=1
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(rownum)
    if creds.access_token_expired:
        client.login()  # refreshes the token
    if i%50==0:
        worksheet.update_cells(cell_matrix)
        cell_matrix = []
        reauthorize()
        #time.sleep(120)
    if creds.access_token_expired:
        client.login()  # refreshes the token
    cellrange = '{start_col}{row}:{last_col}{row}'.format(row=rownum, start_col=get_colname_using_index(colnum), last_col=get_colname_using_index(colnum+len(row)-1))
    # get the row from the worksheet
    cell_list = worksheet.range(cellrange)
    columnnumber = 0
    for cell in row:
        if pd.isnull(cell):
            cell_list[columnnumber].value = ''
        else:
            cell_list[columnnumber].value = cell
        columnnumber += 1
    # add the cell_list, which represents all cells in a row to the full matrix
    cell_matrix = cell_matrix + cell_list
    t_all += (time.time() - t1)
    t1 = time.time()
    #sys.stdout.write("\rrownum: {}, rows: {}; avg time: {} secs; Total time: {} secs".format(rownum, i, t_all/i, t_all))
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    rownum += 1
    i+=1
# output the full matrix all at once to the worksheet.
worksheet.update_cells(cell_matrix)

if resize:
    worksheet.resize(df.shape[0]+init_rownum-1, df.shape[1]+init_colnum-1)
```

The above code throws the following error : gspread.exceptions.APIError: {u'status': u'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', u'message': u"Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:1044022051760'.", u'code': 429, u'details': [{u'reason': u'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', u'@type': u'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', u'domain': u'googleapis.com', u'metadata': {u'quota_metric': u'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests', u'consumer': u'projects/1044022051760', u'service': u'sheets.googleapis.com', u'quota_limit': u'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser'}}]}

Comment: To be a little more specific the particular line of code throws the error:  cell_list = worksheet.range(cellrange)

Comment: try to avoid reading the sheet in the loop. If possible, read values once and process the result sin the loop. If that is not possible, you'll need to handle Http 429 error. Here is a very good retry library I've been using all the time: https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/